# Are there convergence tests for conditional convergence only, besides Leibniz rule and the limit of the summand?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Are there ways to test **conditional** convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n$ (of course after the failure of total, absolute and uniform convergence) when Leibniz rule cannot be used and the series is not telescopic nor it can be rewritten as a known series (like the geometric or the harmonic ones), but the necessary condition for convergence 
$$\mathrm{lim}_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$$is still valid?

Suppose for example that the series is such that the general terms are not of constant sign, neither with alternating sign but still $\mathrm{lim}_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$.

What are the convergence tests used in such situations (if there are any)?

Comment: Dirichlet test?

Comment: Could you expand on what you meant by Leibniz rule?

Answer (score 1):

For problems like

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\cos(n)\over n}$$

Dirichlet test is easily applicable.  It is much more general than the alternating series test, though it holds the same basic idea.

Summations of the form $\sum a_nb_n$ converge if

$b_n$ is positive and monotonically decreasing.

$b_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$

There exists an $M$ such that $\left|\sum_{n=a}^ba_n\right|<M$ for all $a<b$ in the summation.